# Javascript Cropping plugin: Darkroom

Tags: javascript, github, plugins

I finally found a Plugin (http://mattketmo.github.io/darkroomjs/) for Cropping and Rotating my images ;).
My question is how and where I have to implement the function "canvas.toDataURL();". On the Github site is only explained how to write the code not where to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I have used darkroom for my angular 2 project, darkroom gives an object that contains initialized canvas, from where you can get dataUrl. see below example:

```
var _darkroom = new Darkroom('#target');    
var b64Url = _darkroom.canvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: Hi vikas, can you explain or show me how do i have to add/import darkroom to my project please? i've tried using npm but can't import it then on my component, also tried adding as an import directly the darkroom and fabric js but still get many error. Which is the right way as u did the import and further config of the dakroom object?